# Caius the Mega Monarch if targets 2 cards inflicts damage twice?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Caius the Mega Monarch](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Caius_the_Mega_Monarch):

> You can Tribute Summon this card by Tributing 1 Tribute Summoned
>   monster. If this card is Tribute Summoned: Target 1 card on the field;
>   banish it, and if you do, inflict 1000 damage to your opponent, then,
>   if it is a DARK Monster Card, banish all cards with that name from the
>   hand, Main Deck, Extra Deck, and GY of the player who controlled it.
>   If this card was Tribute Summoned by Tributing a DARK monster, add
>   this additional effect. ● **You can target 2 cards, instead**.

If targeted 2 cards, will inflict 1000 or 2000 damage to opponent's LP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The opponent will take 1000 damage.

Think of it like this; if you tribute a dark monster, you modify the activation cost (i.e., instead of "Target 1 card on the field", it becomes "Target 2 cards on the field;"). The effect simply states "Inflict 1000 damage to your opponent." This means that the modified effect would become,

> banish **them**, and if you do, inflict 1000 damage to your opponent, then, if **any of those monsters were DARK Monster Cards**, banish all cards with the same name as those DARK Monster Cards from the hand, Main Deck, Extra Deck, and GY of the player who controlled **them**.

As the 1000 damage is not per card - simply an effect to itself - the amount remains the same.